# Filling a ViewModel that contains other ViewModels with data from LINQ to Entites

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, linq-to-entities

I just finished building a my first complex, well I consider it complex, `ViewModel`. It contains nested `ViewModels` and I am having a hard time figuring out how to fill the entire graph with data using `LINQ to Entities`. How am I supposed to fill the entire graph?

My ViewMode:

```
public class TimesheetWeeklyTableVM
{
    public int TimesheetHeaderID { get; set; }
    //public DateTime weekEndingDate { get; set; }
    public decimal TotalWeekHours { get; set; }

    public List<TimesheetDailyVM> DaysOfWeek { get; set; }

    public TimesheetWeeklyTableVM(DateTime weekEndingDate)
    {
        DaysOfWeek = new List<TimesheetDailyVM>();

        for (var i = 6; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            DaysOfWeek.Add(new TimesheetDailyVM()
            {
                CurrentDate = weekEndingDate.AddDays(-i)
            });
        }
    }
}

public class TimesheetDailyVM
{
    public DateTime CurrentDate { get; set; }

    public double TotalHours
    {
        get
        {
            return TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Tasks.Sum(p => (p.StartDateTime - p.EndDateTime).TotalSeconds)).TotalHours;
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<TimesheetDailyHoursVM> Tasks { get; set; }

    public TimesheetDailyVM()
    {
        Tasks = new List<TimesheetDailyHoursVM>();
    }
}

public class TimesheetDailyHoursVM
{
    public int TimesheetID { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDateTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDateTime { get; set; }
    public string ProjectCode { get; set; }
    public string ProjectDescription { get; set; }
    public string TaskCode { get; set; }
    public string TaskDescription { get; set; }
}
```

The entities I will be pulling data form into the above:

```
public class TimesheetHeader
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public int EmployeeID { get; set; }
    public DateTime WeekEndingDate { get; set; }
    public decimal TotalHours { get; set; }
    public int CurrentStatusID { get; set; }

    public decimal OtherPay { get; set; }
    public int? ApprovedByID { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DateSubmitted { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DateApproved { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "varchar(MAX)")]
    public string ManagerNotes { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("EmployeeID")]
    public Employee Employee { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ApprovedByID")]
    public Employee ApprovedBy { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("CurrentStatusID")]
    public StatusOption CurrentStatus { get; set; }
}

public class Timesheet
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public int TimesheetHeaderID { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDateTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDateTime { get; set; }
    public string ProjectCode { get; set; }
    public string TaskCode { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "varchar(MAX)")]
    public string WorkDescription { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("TimesheetHeaderID")]
    public TimesheetHeader TimesheetHeader { get; set; }
}
```

The code I have so far to fill:

```
            var weekEndingDate = TimesheetHelper.GetWeekEndingDate(date);

            using (var db = new JobSightDbContext())
            {
                var model = db.TimesheetHeaders
                              .Where(timesheet => timesheet.WeekEndingDate == weekEndingDate)
                              .Select(timesheet => new TimesheetWeeklyTableVM(weekEndingDate)
                              {
                                  TimesheetHeaderID = timesheet.ID,
                                  TotalWeekHours = timesheet.TotalHours
                              }).FirstOrDefault();

                model.DaysOfWeek = db.Timesheets
                                     .Where(timesheet => timesheet.TimesheetHeaderID == model.TimesheetHeaderID)
                                     .OrderBy(timesheet => timesheet.StartDateTime)
                                     .Select(timesheet => new TimesheetDailyVM()
                                     {   
                                         Tasks.TimesheetID = timesheet.ID,
                                         StartDateTime = timesheet.StartDateTime,
                                         EndDateTime = timesheet.EndDateTime,
                                         ProjectCode = timesheet.ProjectCode,
                                         TaskCode = timesheet.TaskCode
                                     }).ToList();

                return PartialView(model);
            }
```

This code gives me the errors "The name 'Tasks' does not exist in the current context. INvalid initializer member declaratory" and "TimesheeDailyVM does not contain a definition for 'XXX'"

If I try to case into `TimesheetDailyHoursVM` then I get an implicit conversion error.

Comment: `Tasks` is `IEnumerable<TimesheetDailyHoursVM>` and does not contain a property `TimesheetID`. Nor does `TimesheetDailyVM` contain properties `StartDateTime`, `EndDateTime` etc. (they are properties of `TimesheetDailyHoursVM`)

Comment: @StephenMuecke Sorry, I am missing your point. The code is just what I have one screen right now after many different combinations of properties and casts but nothing I try works. This is broken code that I can't get working to fill the graph.

Comment: Just explaining why it does not work. Need to examine you models a bit more, but what I think you wanting to do is group your `db.Timesheets` by date and then add each group result as a `TimesheetDailyHoursVM` to its corresponding `Tasks`

Comment: Is the idea here to create a weekly time sheet and display the records for each day - i.e Monday might have 2 records and Tuesday 5 records? or are you just wanting a summary of records for each day?

Comment: @StephenMuecke Yes, the goal is to present weekly timesheet and display the records of the tasks for each day worked inside a table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to display records for each day of the week, you will need to group the `Timesheet` records by date, and add each corresponding group to the associated `Tasks` property of the corresponding day

```
var timeRecords = db.Timesheets
    .Where(x => x.TimesheetHeaderID == model.TimesheetHeaderID)
    .Groupby(x => x.StartDateTime);

foreach(var group in timeRecords)
{
    var index = // see notes below
    model.DaysOfWeek[index].Tasks = group.Select(x => new TimesheetDailyHoursVM()
    {
        TimesheetID = x.ID,
        StartDateTime = x.StartDateTime,
        ....
    });
}
```

In above, `index` needs to be based on the `group.Key` which is the `StartDateTime`. Typically this would be

```
index = group.Key.DayOfWeek;
```

which would be `0` for Sunday, `1` for Monday etc. but in your code your using

```
for (var i = 6; i >= 0; i--)
{
    DaysOfWeek.Add(new TimesheetDailyVM()
    {
        CurrentDate = weekEndingDate.AddDays(-i)
    });
}
```

and its not clear if the first day is in fact Sunday

Comment: Sunday is in fact the first day. I don't think I can do a `Groupby` for `StartDateTime` since that is a full `DateTime` so each task for a single day would have a different value.

Comment: Then use `.GroupBy(x => x.StartDateTime.Date)` or even `Then use .GroupBy(x => x.StartDateTime.DayOfWeek)` which would mean the `Key` is the index so it could be `model.DaysOfWeek[group.Key].Tasks = ...`

Comment: Thanks, I did not think you could use the sub systems like that in `LINQ to Entities` and it was something I was planning on using but I was stuck on other projects/meetings the whole day. I will give this all a shot on Monday and see what happens.

Comment: Note that you may need to materialize the query using `var timeRecords = db.Timesheets.Where(...).ToList().Groupby(x => x.StartDateTime.DayOfWeek);`

Comment: I have been trying to set this in place and am getting a "non-static method requires a target" on the `var timeRecords` LINQ query. Am I needing to cast this into a one of my `ViewModels` or select into an anonymous type?

Comment: Did you try the `db.Timesheets.Where(...).ToList().Groupby(..` option so that its materialized to memory? (which will be needed if your using `x.StartDateTime.DayOfWeek`)

Comment: Yes, if I don't do `.ToList()` first then I get an error along the lines of `DayOfWeek` not being valid in a `LINQ` expression.

Comment: That's because your using Linq to SQL and SQL does not understand `DayOfWeek` (adding `.ToList()` materializes it to an in-memory set and then uses Linq to Entities. I cant see why you would be getting a `non-static method requires a target` error but I'll test it later and see if I can repeat it.

Comment: But just as a check, before that query, add `var headerID = model.TimesheetHeaderID;` and then in the query, replace `model.TimesheetHeaderID` with `headerID`

Comment: I just tried that and it seemed to get rid of the error but I was getting others, so I removed it to see what would happen and now I can't get the non-static method error anymore. Not sure why I can't reproduce but the code is now work, well except other errors which have nothing to do with this problem. I appreciate the help.